# Syntax error while using WHERE clause in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

I'm trying to run some queries related to the University database in PostgreSQL.
To find students advised by instructors from different departments, I used-

```
select distinct s_id from advisor
where (s_id ,i_id) in (select distinct student.id,instructor.id from
student join instructor where student.dept_name <> instructor.dept_name);
```

However im getting the following error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "where"
>
> LINE 3: student join instructor where student.dept_name <>
> instructo...

Any fix?

Comment: The JOIN needs an `ON` term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
select distinct s_id from advisor
where (s_id ,i_id) in (select distinct student.id,instructor.id from
student join instructor on student.dept_name <> instructor.dept_name);
```

Instead of where you need to use `on` clause with join.